# Cross table update in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

I'm writing a trigger that will do a cross table update, but I can't get the desired result. I'm working with one param, and that is messageId. Using that messageId, I need to go into the messages table and find the userId @messageId, then update his/her score: **(@messageId is coming from an insert into a third table, so really it's NEW.messageId)**

```
      UPDATE users
      SET users.score = users.score + 1
      WHERE users.id = messages.userId
```

I need to select messages.userId @messageId from messages, but the trigger will not let me do a select statement, so I'm a bit stuck!

I tried this, which does not seem to work either:

```
      UPDATE users, messages
      INNER JOIN messages ON messages.id = NEW.messageId
      SET users.score = users.score + 1
      WHERE users.id = messages.userId
```

PS: I'm not really looking to select anything, I just want to update the users table by referencing it though the messages table, which is in turn being referenced by NEW.messageId

Comment: Which table is the Trigger on?

Comment: A third table all together, VoodooChild!

Comment: does this work WITHOUT the INNER JOIN line?  The comma in this scenario serves as the join.

Comment: @Christopher, no; I think it's because the trigger has no way to reference NEW.messageId

Comment: @Chris, sorry that was the opposite. But the answer is still no, and in that case I'm unsure why. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of there being a way to insert a select statement into a trigger. However, you can use the following syntax if you are looking to monitor for changes in a user's score:

```
CREATE TRIGGER score_update
    BEFORE UPDATE ON score_table
    REFERENCING NEW ROW AS n, OLD ROW AS o
    FOR EACH ROW
    IF n.score <> o.score
    THEN
    END IF;
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Triggers are not supposed to be used for selects, they are there to perform update, inserts or deletes after some action like an update or insert/delete has taken place.

Refer to:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

for a primer on MySql triggers.

Answer (score 1):

In order for a multi-table update to occur, there needs to be a join EVEN if the joined table is not updated.  A simple comma acts as shorthand or you can use any JOIN syntax.  In your case, simply add messages.

```
      UPDATE users, messages
      SET users.score = users.score + 1
      WHERE users.id = messages.userId
```

Comment: Christopher, the problem is the trigger is coming from a third table, so the reference really is New.messgeId